# Applications show as <Application>.app instead of <Application> in Alfred & Spotlight

Tags: applications, spotlight

I do not know the actual time or date of the change, but I noticed it today.

Example: I use Alfred which now shows "Word.app" instead of "Word".

Same goes for Spotlight.

EDIT: How do I remove the .app for my applications?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Did you try rebuilding spotlight index? See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142523/115093) for details - it worked in this similar question: [.app extension in Spotlight or Alfred](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33381/115093)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Finder's (advanced) preferences is set to "Show all filename extensions" - I like that, actually!

So you would uncheck this box to hide the .app extension.